# Identify plant from genus *Solanum*

Tags: botany

This spring we have recieved from a local Botanical garden in Southern Germany a pack of seeds with the label "surprise". We could grow one plant from the seeds, the seeds looked like "pepper" = Paprika *Capsicum annuum* seeds. The plant got about 50 cm high and bore one fruit of 5 cm length including the trunk. The leaf in the picture has 10 cm total length. It has a very rough backside but not really hairy one. Also the upper side feels rough but there are no hairs. Also some yellow flower can be seen.

Initially I thought it is some *capsicum* so I cut it but was surprised when I saw the thick pulp. The skin is also quite strong and like very soft leather. It has a nice sweetish taste and some remembrance of lemon in taste but also some exotic "veggie" note. What could that plant be?

After searching the web my idea was that it could be *Solanum sessiliflorum* DUNAL, that is Amazonian tomato or "cocona". But I am not sure at all. Any hints appreciated!

[image: "surprise plant: it got about 50 cm in height and bore one fruit of 5 cm length including the trunk. The leaf in the picture has 10 cm total length.]

Comment: If I were you I would probably ask the garden :)

Comment: Yes, I had already that thought as well ;-)